# Get combobox selected value in edit row in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have create a code for GrideViewServer.FooterRow to get selected value of dropdownlist in footer row(insert). Now I want to do same thing for edit row to get selected value from combobox, however they are not in footer row.

Here what I write for footer row,

```
string architecture = ((DropDownList)GridViewServer
         .FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownArchitecture")).Text;
```

Now I want to write for edit row, how can I write it? Something like this?

```
string architecture = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox)GridViewServer
         .EditRow.FindControl("ComboBox1")).Text;
```

Can't find options function for edit section.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have only one EditRow, you have a collection of rows of this type, to find a control inside, you need to iterate using `for` or `foreach`:

```
    foreach (GridViewRow r in GridViewServer.Rows)
    {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string architecture = ((AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox)r.FindControl("ComboBox1")).Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Here what I wrote,

```
((AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox)GridViewServer.Rows[GridViewServer.EditIndex].FindControl("Combobox2")).Text;
```